# GridView Column

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net

I have a GridView bound with table, I added one hyperlink field as you can see the code below:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField NavigateUrl="~/Logout.aspx?category=Mobile&&ID=" Text ="logout"/>
```

As you can see that I am sending 2 query string with URL. I am getting both correctly as long as I am sending static data. The problem is that I want to send one of my GridView column value through query string something like this I want and I tried:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField NavigateUrl="~/Logout.aspx?category=Mobile&&ID='<%GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text.ToString%>'" Text ="logout"/>
```

I am not getting the ID value as per column value but the same Gridview code like this

```
GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells(1).Text.ToString
```

How should I correct this syntax so i can send my column value through URL?

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to convert the field to a template field and bind the asp:HyperLink's NavigateUrl property in the DataBound event of the GridView.

Examples can be found here (using BulletedList instead of HyperLink):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx